# Configuring FreeMarker In Spring Application

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am new to freemarker,but i want to fetch the data from Spring Application to my view which has extension `.ftl`.I am using `${message}` but it displays as usual.It should display the data which is availble in message from Spring Application.

I am configured  dispatcherServlet as below

```
   <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
       <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
      </bean>

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="cache" value="true"/>
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
       <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `InternalResourceViewResolver` with Freemarker, you use `FreemarkerViewResolver`. Replace that, you should be fine.

Also, I suggest not putting your freemarker templates in `/WEB-INF/jsp`. They're *not* JSPs, and should never be treated as such.